# How to fix "TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Lt.Subject')" in Angular --prod build? Works with --optimization=false

Tags: angular-cli, typeerror

The Angular app runs well in dev mode and even with `--prod --optimization=false`, but when I build with `--prod --optimization=true` (I guess optimization is true by default), I get the error below.

Any ideas on where to look for the error or how to debug this error? I'm also pasting my package.json dependencies below in addition if that helps.

```
[Error] ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Lt.Subject') t@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:2258798 https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:2259766 pr@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:166340 fr@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:165313 https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:4983103 pr@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:166340 https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:230109 Os@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:230170 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:304618 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:201118 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1469275 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1421987 https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1420976 forEach@[native code] value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1420946 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1419636 https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1454212 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393084 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1510529 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393182 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:807039 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:438224 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393182 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393796 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:109038 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108825 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:806530 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:806359 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:807039 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:438224 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393182 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1510529 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:807039 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:438224 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1510529 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:99363 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:438224 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:99363 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:438224 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393796 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:109038 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108825 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:99137 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:99031 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:98851 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:334008 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:102156 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:102156 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:99282 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:102156 https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393813 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:109038 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108825 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:99137 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:99031 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:98851 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393796 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:109038 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108825 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:806530 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:806359 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1510529 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:393796 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:109038 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108825 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:108694 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:806530 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:806359 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1317286 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/main.a7aa466b736f5543d287.js:1:1510529 value@https://xxx.info/beta/app/styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101984
w — polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:14646
w — polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:14165
(tuntematon funktio) — polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:15437
onInvokeTask — styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:336076
(tuntematon funktio) — polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:4143
y — polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:11377
(tuntematon funktio) — polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:10216
g — polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:23267
m — polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:23568
    Or (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:167955)
    value (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:168198)
    next (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:343905)
    (tuntematon funktio) (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:310767)
    value (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:104327)
    value (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:103474)
    value (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:102354)
    value (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:101985)
    value (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:115827)
    value (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:310544)
    (tuntematon funktio) (polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:3476)
    onHandleError (styles.f0239b81073897b8f4c1.js:1:336479)
    (tuntematon funktio) (polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:3694)
    t (polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:13295)
    (tuntematon funktio) (polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:13443)
    y (polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:11444)
    (tuntematon funktio) (polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:10216)
    g (polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:23267)
    m (polyfills.e2119ff0d0c4c3dc72e3.js:1:23568)
```

package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "11.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/core": "11.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/forms": "11.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.0.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^11.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.0-rc.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.3.1",
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-fittext": "^2.1.1",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.9.8",
    "angular2-lightbox": "^1.4.1",
    "angular2-loaders-css": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-tooltips": "^1.0.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "fsevents": "^2.1.3",
    "hammer-timejs": "^1.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lightbox2": "^2.11.3",
    "mammoth": "^1.4.13",
    "md-tooltip": "0.0.1-alpha.1",
    "ng2-component-spinner": "^0.2.1",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-scroll-to-el": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.9.1",
    "ngx-contextmenu": "^5.4.0",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.7.5",
    "ngx-quill": "^12.0.1",
    "ngx-sortablejs": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.2.0",
    "npm": "^7.0.7",
    "popper": "^1.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-image-uploader": "^1.2.2",
    "raf": "^3.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "sortablejs": "^1.12.0",
    "tether": "^1.4.7",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.0-rc.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.14.13",
    "@types/sortablejs": "^1.10.6",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.8.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0"
  }
```

Building without optimization is not an option because of the gigantic file size it produces, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this issue could be because of many things. To help debug such a matter, it helps to remove the scrambled variable and class names to see actual names.

To do this, you can run the app locally in production mode without variable name mangling by running:
`env NG_BUILD_MANGLE=false NG_BUILD_MINIFY=false NG_BUILD_BEAUTIFY=true ng serve --prod`

This way it's easier to see where the incorrect call is being made.

In this case, what caused the error was that I imported Subject from rxjs by using `Import Subject from 'rxjs/Subject'` - it seems this kind of imports should be now replaced with `Import Subject from 'rxjs'`.